# Can I determine this RAM slot is damaged?

Tags: memory, motherboard, hardware-failure, memtest86+

While playing around with some old parts, I ended up with the following hardware setup:

- Mobo: ASROCK 775Dual-VSTA (2x DDRII slots)
- RAM: 2x Kingston DDRII 533 1GB (KVR533D2N4/1G)

I noticed stability problems (BSOD), so the first though was the posibility of memmory troubles. I performed the following tests with memtest86:

1. Module "A" on slot 0 + Module "B" on slot 1. Errors were reported.
2. Module "A" on slot 0. No errors reported.
3. Module "B" on slot 0. No errors reported.
4. Module "B" on slot 1. Errors were reported.
5. Module "A" on slot 1. Errors were reported.

### Can I assume this motherboard has the DDRII slot 1 damaged?

---

Why is this question diferent from [how to check of RAM Slot is broken](https://superuser.com/questions/417500/how-to-check-of-ram-slot-is-broken):

- This question asks one concise thing: Advice on identifying a damaged RAM slot.
- The other question asks: *"how could i see if the RAM Slot is broken"* and *"in case it is how could i fix it"*
- This question refers to a completely different research procedure prior to asking the question itself.

Comment: Your first test might not tell you too much. It is ideal if you test all your RAM sticks individually, as you might get false errors. Based on your results however, it would appear that your motherboard has issues with "slot 1".

Comment: Just because you used a different OS and testing utiltiy doesn't make it a different question (to me anyway). Test each stick in each slot, if the slot is where the errors stick (instead of following the RAM stick) it's a bad slot.  How is your question/and self-answer any more useful than the information already offered there?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I read on the help center: "If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site." **I simply tried to write down the research I did with this particular case, as editing the other question would change it completely.**

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 This question asks **if it's assumible that slot, after performing that tests, is broken**. The research and troubleshooting procedure is explained to ilustrate the whole scenario. **The answer assumes, as you state, the fact that troubleshooting this is not different from other posible hardware setups neither test utilities: "As simple as try each module on each slot".**

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 To summarize, this question is about *"Can I assume this motherboard has the DDRII slot 1 damaged (after doing this)?"* while the other one is asking *"how could i check if the memory slot is broken and in case it is how could i fix it?*

Answer (score 1):

As read [the mentioned question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/417500/how-to-check-of-ram-slot-is-broken) and [also](http://www.passmark.com/forum/showthread.php?4669-RAM-issues-DIMM-module-issues-Memtest86-(version-4-20)-showing-errors-on-test-6&s=f696d1f3afb1a0eb00a8be6fad168faf&p=17240#post17240) on [other](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/327791-30-memtest-lying#4460101) sources:

> It is easy to test for a bad slot, just take one module at time and try it in each slot.
>
> What you need to do is test every memory modules in every slot. If you repeatedly get errors on one slot with every module, but not on the other slot(s), then you would have a very strong case for a bad slot.

### So definetively you have a very strong case of a bad slot.